# Best numerical scheme for this problem

Tags: finite-difference, numerical-analysis

I have a set of data, $x, y$ and $ z$, each with length n:

$x \rightarrow \{x_{1}...x_{n}\}$

$y \rightarrow \{y_{1}...y_{n}\}$

$z \rightarrow \{z_{1}...z_{n}\}$

$y$ and $z$ are parameterised by $x$:

$y = y(x)$

$z = z(x)$

---

**Problem 1**

I wish to find derivatives $\Large \frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\Large \frac{dz}{dx}$.

The 'second-order error' numerical scheme:
$\Large \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y(x+dx)-y(x-dx)}{2dx} + \mathcal{O}({dx}^{2})$

woud usually work, but in my case, my 'x' data is not uniformly spaced (it is nonlinear) i.e. '$dx$' is not constant (hence my problem turns into a first order error one). The problem applies for the derivative of z.

Can anyone suggest a good method to find these derivatives? (for anyone interested in meteorology, $x$ are pressure coordinates in atmosphere, $y$ is the potential temperature, $z$ is the geopotential height).

One person suggested that I interpolate $x$, $y$ and $z$ onto a new $x$ whereby this new list of $x$ values are uniformly spaced. However, I also want to see how the error introduced here propagates to the end result.

---

**Problem 2**

I wish to find the derivative: $\Large \frac{dy}{dz}$. However, as my $z$ are not necessarily spaced evenly between each other, my numerical scheme is not second order. Hence, what scheme should I use and what is my resulting error, preferably as a function of $x$. I guess it's a similar problem to above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best numerical scheme, however, it should work well with second order accuracy.

**Problem 1**: you can apply the following second order approximation
\begin{align}
\left( 
\frac{dy}{ dx}
\right)_i
&=
\frac{ 
y_{i+1} (\Delta x_{i} )^2  -
y_{i-1} ( \Delta x_{i+1}  )^2  +
y_{i} \left( (\Delta x_{i+1})^2 - (\Delta x_{i})^2  \right)
}{ \Delta x_{i} \Delta x_{i+1}  \left( \Delta x_{i} + \Delta x_{i+1} \right) } ~~+
\\
&~~~~
-  \frac{\Delta x_{i+1}  \Delta x_{i} }{ 6}
\left( \frac{d^3 y }{ dx ^3} \right)_i +
\textrm{Higher-Order-Terms}
\\
&\simeq 
\frac{ 
y_{i+1} (\Delta x_{i} )^2  -
y_{i-1} ( \Delta x_{i+1}  )^2  +
y_{i} \left( (\Delta x_{i+1})^2 - (\Delta x_{i})^2  \right)
}{ \Delta x_{i} \Delta x_{i+1}  \left( \Delta x_{i} + \Delta x_{i+1} \right) }
\end{align}
for $2 \le i \le n-1$, where $\Delta x_{i} = x_{i}  - x_{i-1}$. For the end-points, i.e. $i=1$ and $i=n$, one can adopt the one-side approximations
\begin{align}
\left( 
\frac{dy}{ dx}
\right)_1
&\simeq 
\frac{ 
- y_{3} ( x_2 -x_1 )^2  +
y_{2} ( x_3 - x_1 )^2  -
y_{1} \left( (x_3 -x_1)^2 - (x_2 - x_1 )^2 \right)
}{ (x_2-x_1)(x_3-x_1)(x_3-x_2) }, 
\\
\left( 
\frac{dy}{ dx}
\right)_n
&\simeq 
\frac{ 
y_{n-2} ( x_n -x_{n-1} )^2  -
y_{n-1} ( x_{n} - x_{n-2} )^2  +
y_{n} \left( ( x_{n} - x_{n-2} )^2 - ( x_{n} - x_{n-1} )^2 \right)
}{ ( x_n -x_{n-1} ) ( x_n -x_{n-2} ) ( x_{n-1} -x_{n-2} ) } ,
\end{align}
which also have second order accuracy on any grid. For further reading, you can read [the excellent book of Ferziger and Peric, Chapter 3](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-642-56026-2).

Regarding **Problem 2**, you can apply the idea from Wolfgang Bangerth's post, i.e. $$ \left( \frac{ d y }{ d z } \right)_i = \frac{ \left( \frac{dy }{dx} \right)_i }{ \left( \frac{ dz}{ dx} \right)_i } $$ for any $i=1,2,..,n$.

Answer (score 3):

*For Problem 1:* You could use the forward-looking one-sided finite difference scheme,
$$
  \frac{dy(x_k)}{dx} \approx \frac{y_{k+1}-y_k}{x_{k+1}-x_k}.
$$
Of course, you could equally well have used the backward looking scheme:
$$
  \frac{dy(x_k)}{dx} \approx \frac{y_k-y_{k-1}}{x_k-x_{k-1}}.
$$
To make it more accurate, you can also average them:
$$
  \frac{dy(x_k)}{dx} \approx 
  \frac 12 \frac{y_{k+1}-y_k}{x_{k+1}-x_k}
  +
  \frac 12 \frac{y_k-y_{k-1}}{x_k-x_{k-1}}.
$$

*For Problem 2:* Use the chain rule:
$$
  \frac{dz}{dy}=\frac{\frac{dz}{dx}}{\frac{dy}{dx}}.
$$